# Stuck on Lagrange solve don't seem to have enough constraints yet told to use Lagrange

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

Find maxima and minima for $f(x,y)=x-2y$
with the constraint $g(x,y)= 4x^2+y^2-17$ using Lagrange

I'm stuck on lagrange on this problem. I get
$<1,-2>= \lambda<8x,2y>$
And solve that to get $y=8x$ but don't know what to do from here

There is also a part b which wants how much would f change if g increased by 1 and it would be $1/\lambda$ right?

Comment: Some help in general with Lagrange multiplier problems: as long as something is known to be nonzero, you can divide by it. This means you can divide $1=8\lambda x$ by $-2=2\lambda y$ to get $-1/2=4x/y$ or equivalently $y=-8x$. As for the last thing, if the Lagrange condition is $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ then increasing the constrained value of $g$ by a small amount $\epsilon$ usually causes the extremal value of $f$ to change by approximately $\lambda \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $4x^2+y^2-17$ is *not* a constraint. I will assume that the constraint is $4x^2+y^2-17=0$. It's not enough to do $(1,-2)=\lambda(8x,2y)$; $(x,y)$ must also be such that $g(x,y)=0$. So, you have *three* equations:$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}1=8\lambda x\\-2=2\lambda y\\4x^2+y^2=17.\end{array}\right.$$Its solutions are$$x=-\frac12,y=4,\lambda=-\frac14\quad\text{and}\quad x=\frac12,y=-4,\lambda=\frac14.$$